# Access command line options in Julia

Tags: julia

When I type

```
$ julia -p 2 run.jl
```

is there any way to access the `2` from within `run.jl`? I know that one can use `ARGS` to access arguments, for example

```
#run.jl
println(ARGS[2])
```

and running

```
$ julia -p 2 run.jl a b c d
```

would return `b`. But I can't seem to find a way to access the options `-p <n>`.

Comment: I think your program shouldn't normally look at arguments to julia directly but rather their result on the programs environment, here on procs()/workers(). Otherwise, you may assume arguments represent the state despite adjustments in the user's startup.jl, later changes to julia's commandline, the user's specification to use remote processes instead, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 0.4+, you can access the parsed options via `Base.JLOptions()`, so your argument to `-p` would be here:

```
Base.JLOptions().nprocs
```